# Are probability graphic models useful for predictive modelling?

Tags: data-mining, bayesian-network

Are Probability Graphic Models (say specifically Bayesian Networks) useful for predictive modelling in terms of large data (100,000 - 1,000,000 rows) and many variables (hundreds)?

Meaning, is this technique / methodology something that can be a competitor for, say random forests or some machine learning method for classification/regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the particularities of the problem. PGM (and BN) can be very effective - there are many algorithms and adaptations tailored to problems with certain specifications. Also, quite often part of solving a problem using PGMs uses at some point standard ML techniques. It is more likely that PGMs and ML will reinforce each other rather than competing against each other.